# Cannot update Firefox with locale-fr (french)

Tags: software-installation, firefox, language-support, locale, accessibility

Update manager offers new updates : Firefox 34.0 plus French package - I installed it.

I started Firefox and everything is in English. Tried via terminal to `apt-get firefox-locale-fr`, but it says I have the most recent version.

I retry Firefox (still in English) and I presume this is the cause that Firefox does not start, I get `error Firefox already running but not responding`.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking, can you be more specific about what exactly you're asking?

Comment: Have you changed to French in [Language Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-language.html)?

Comment: My computer is all in French, Ubuntu 14.04LTS on dec 02 in the list of update was Firefox34.0 with French language packgage after update finish open Firefox wich say checking add-ons then open

Comment: My computer is all in French, Ubuntu 14.04LTS on dec 02 in the list of update was Firefox 34.0 with French language packgage after update finish open Firefox wich say checking add-ons then Firefox start but all the menus are in English. Try to install via Terminal firefox-locale-fr get answer file is most recent on computer. But menus are still all in English. So how to I get the French language pack to work

Comment: In language Support there is only French and English Canada check

Comment: 1. Edit - Preferences - Content - Languages.  What does it show?
2. general.useragent.locale. Qu'y-at-il dedans?

Comment: Edit-Preferences-Content-Languages = French CA and English

Comment: To get Firefox to start had to remove each time .parentlock So decided to uninstall firefox, got firefox to work backup bookmarks then uninstall, delete the profile, reinstall Firefox and every things is OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I backed up my bookmarks and reinstalled Firefox, and the problem was solved.